# split string not working in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to split the following: 116,24|426,776 into two strings upon the | symbol.

My code:

```
String[] splitString = "116,24|462,776".split("|");
System.out.println(splitString[1]);
```

However, this code simply returns: 1

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use escape character.

Try this `String[] splitString = "116,24|462,776".split("\\|");`

Here `\\` is the escape character.

Please refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html